# Convert Json output into good looking text?

Tags: python, json, file, text

I am trying to retrieve data from the site: 
https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/cardano/?convert=usd

the code snippet looks like this:

```
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/cardano/?convert=USD") as url:
data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
print(data)
```

The output is:

[{'id': 'cardano', 'name': 'Cardano', 'symbol': 'ADA', 'rank': '5', 'price_usd': '0.81872', 'price_btc': '0.00005809', '24h_volume_usd': '213316000.0', 'market_cap_usd': '21227011191.0', 'available_supply': '25927070538.0', 'total_supply': '31112483745.0', 'max_supply': '45000000000.0', 'percent_change_1h': '0.19', 'percent_change_24h': '13.13', 'percent_change_7d': '-19.93', 'last_updated': '1515768856'}]

My problem is, how do I work with that text? Can I make it into a better looking list?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I'm working with Python right now

Comment: Working with it and making it prettier are 2 distinct things.

Comment: Would I not need to work with it to make it prettier?

Comment: I suppose that depends on what you want to DO with it, which you have provided no hint to.

Comment: I'm sorry then.

My plan is to use the variables e.g. price_usd somewhere else in my program. Can I make it to a variable, since I haven't found out how to talk to it?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can just use it like a dictionary. So something like `price = data['price_usd']`should work.

Comment: so you would like a list. Could you provice a format of list into to convert json object?

Comment: I tried    price = data['price_usd'] but it keeps getting me error messges:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Then tried    price = data[3] e.g. but doesn't work either.

I looked up trying to make it into an object but since my python skills are very bad I couldn't find it out

Answer (score 2):

To get the price_usd element, you can use `data[0]['price_usd']`.

You can use the `pprint` module to print it in a nicer format.

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

This will break out into a much more easily readable view of your pull.  But I'm not sure that it would make it any easier for you to work with the info within your script.  pprint is another great module.

Answer (score -1):

I would very much recommend using the `requests` library for doing this kind of things. It's suuuuper flexible and is kind of the de-facto lib for doing requesty stuff.

For example (in which I took the liberty of using such lib, and iPython):

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: r = requests.get("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/cardano/?convert=USD")

In [3]: r.status_code
Out[3]: 200

In [4]: r.json()
Out[4]:
[{'24h_volume_usd': '198429000.0',
  'available_supply': '25927070538.0',
  'id': 'cardano',
  'last_updated': '1515772155',
  'market_cap_usd': '20403048889.0',
  'max_supply': '45000000000.0',
  'name': 'Cardano',
  'percent_change_1h': '-3.09',
  'percent_change_24h': '5.94',
  'percent_change_7d': '-22.7',
  'price_btc': '0.00005650',
  'price_usd': '0.78694',
  'rank': '5',
  'symbol': 'ADA',
  'total_supply': '31112483745.0'}]

In [5]: usd = r.json()[0].get('price_usd')

In [6]: usd
Out[6]: '0.78694'
```

And if you wanted to print the response as a string, you can use the built-in lib `json` (for dumping it into a file or whatever):

```
In [8]: import json

In [10]: json.dumps(r.text, indent=2)
Out[10]: '"[\\n    {\\n        \\"id\\": \\"cardano\\", \\n        \\"name\\": \\"Cardano\\", \\n        \\"symbol\\": \\"ADA\\", \\n        \\"rank\\": \\"5\\", \\n        \\"price_usd\\": \\"0.78694\\", \\n        \\"price_btc\\": \\"0.00005650\\", \\n        \\"24h_volume_usd\\": \\"198429000.0\\", \\n        \\"market_cap_usd\\": \\"20403048889.0\\", \\n        \\"available_supply\\": \\"25927070538.0\\", \\n        \\"total_supply\\": \\"31112483745.0\\", \\n        \\"max_supply\\": \\"45000000000.0\\", \\n        \\"percent_change_1h\\": \\"-3.09\\", \\n        \\"percent_change_24h\\": \\"5.94\\", \\n        \\"percent_change_7d\\": \\"-22.7\\", \\n        \\"last_updated\\": \\"1515772155\\"\\n    }\\n]"'
```